# Do sport players have pension rights?

Tags: finances

Do players have pension benefits or retirement plans?

Unlike other employees, they can't work until the age of 65 and usually have a second career after they retire from their sport, generally before the age of 40.

Is there something official?

Comment: Does this question refer to athletes in the tagged leagues only? ... all american leagues/sports associations? or globally?

Answer (score 3):

All major leagues in USA have Players Association who have official pension benefits plan for their players.
Those plans contain retirement benefits and other rights.

The players are eligible for a pension from the players association league they belong in:

1) [National Football League Players Association](https://www.nflplayers.com/)

[Full NFL pension plan](http://nflalumniasssociation.files.wordpress.com/2011/03/nfl-player-retirement-plan.pdf)

> The NFL Players Association retirement plan package includes four
>   plans:
>
> 1. Severance Pay Plan: A player with two credited NFL seasons (on the active roster, injured reserved or physically unable to perform list
>      for three games in each of two seasons), receives $10,000 for every
>      year played between 1993 and 1999 and $12,500 for every year from 2000
>      on.
> 2. Player Annuity Program: A player with four credited NFL seasons receives an annuity valued at $65,000 at age 35 or five years after
>      his last credited season, whichever is later.
> 3. Second-Career Savings Plan or 401(K): A player with two credited seasons will receive a $2 match for every $1 contributed to the plan
>      up to a maximum club contribution of $20,000 per year.
> 4. Bert Bell/Pete Rozelle Retirement Plan (pension): A player with at least three credited seasons earns a benefit credit for every season
>      he plays. The benefit credits add up to monthly pension checks that
>      player receive starting at age 55.

2) [National Basketball Players Association (NBPA)](http://www.nbpa.org/)

[Full NBA pension plan](http://www.nbpa.org/sites/default/files/Article%20IV.pdf)

The pension plan in the NBA is calculated as $306 for every month in the NBA.

> For example Gary Payton played in the NBA for 17 seasons or 204 months.
>   204x306=62,424. Gary Payton's pension will be $62,424 per year or
>   $5,202 per month. A player with only three years in the NBA would get
>   $11, 016 per year or $918 per month.

The pension is eligable to players strating the age of 50, 
A player can opt to collect the pension at the age of 45 but only 2/3 of what it would be at 50.
The minimum season to be eligible to NBA pension is three seasons of playing.

3) [Major League Baseball Players Association](http://mlbplayers.mlb.com/pa/index.jsp)

[Full MLB pension plan](http://www.bizofbaseball.com/docs/MLBPABenefitsPlan.pdf)

> Arguably, Major League Baseball (“MLB”) offers one of the best pension
>   and healthcare programs in all of sports. Players vest in their
>   pensions after 43 days on the active roster and just one day qualifies
>   a player for lifetime healthcare. Playing isn’t even a requirement,
>   benchwarmers may qualify for benefits as well. After 43 days, players
>   qualify for the minimum benefit of $34,000 per year and those with 10
>   years of service receive a pension of approximately $100,000 annually.
>   In 2010, the MLB Players’ Pension Plan reported assets of over $1.3
>   billion for approximately 8,200 participants.

4) [National Hockey League Players Association](http://www.nhlpa.com/)

[Full NHL pension plan](http://www.nhlfa.com/CBA/cba_agreement21.asp)

> 21.2.    Basic Plan Benefits.
>
> (a) Each player entitled to a full credited year of service for the 1993/94 playing season and thereafter shall have allocated and
>   credited to an account established in his name, for his sole benefit,
>   the following:
>
> (i) for players who have received credit for less than 400 games played, the amount of $8,000 CDN per year; and
>
> (ii) for players who have received credit for 400 games played or more, the amount of $12,500 CDN per year.

Sources: [1](http://savannahnow.com/adam-van-brimmer/2006-09-29/qualifying-nfl-pension-big-deal-players#.UKuD8Icz18E) [2](http://changwatters.com/?page_id=557) [3](http://www.lvrj.com/sports/pension-is-players-safety-net-84371812.html) [4](http://benefitsbryancave.com/major-league-baseball-pension-and-healthcare-benefits/) [5](http://fehrtheewell.com/2012/06/28/understanding-the-cba-pension-plan/)